In my C raylib project, something strange is happening
In this code, the dog is meant to "eat" the bone, but instead of the bone being eaten, the dog moves away from the bone! I think this game is trolling me.
#include "raylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "raymath.h"
#include <time.h>

#define HEIGHT 500
#define WIDTH 700

Color extraDarkGreen = {10,30,20,255};

int main(void)
{

    InitWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Random");
    Image doge = LoadImage("/home/neraan/C/rand/Doge.png");
    ImageResize(&doge, 75, 75);
    Texture2D dogeTex = LoadTextureFromImage(doge);

    Image Bone = LoadImage("/home/neraan/C/rand/Bone.png");
    ImageResize(&Bone, 75, 75);
    Texture2D BoneTex = LoadTextureFromImage(Bone);

    Vector2 DogePos = {50,50};

    Vector2 BonePos = {GetRandomValue(10, WIDTH-10),GetRandomValue(10, HEIGHT-10)};

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        Rectangle DogeHit = {DogePos.x,DogePos.y,20,20};
        Rectangle BoneHit = {BonePos.x,BonePos.y,20,20};

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(extraDarkGreen);
        DrawTexture(dogeTex, DogePos.x, DogePos.y,GREEN);
        DrawTexture(BoneTex, BonePos.x, BonePos.y,GREEN);

        EndDrawing();

        DogePos.x += GetRandomValue(1.0f,2.0f);
        DogePos.x -= GetRandomValue(1.0f,2.0f);
        DogePos.y -= GetRandomValue(1.0f,2.0f);
        DogePos.y += GetRandomValue(1.0f,2.0f);

        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)) DogePos.x += 4.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT)) DogePos.x -= 4.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_UP)) DogePos.y -= 4.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_DOWN)) DogePos.y += 4.0f;

         if (CheckCollisionRecs(DogeHit,BoneHit))
        {
            SetRandomSeed((unsigned int)time(NULL));
            Vector2 BonePos = {GetRandomValue(10, WIDTH-10),GetRandomValue(10, HEIGHT-10)};
            puts("Lets GOOOO");
        }


    }




    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}

Here's an image of the output:

I have absolutely no idea what even to try. Stack Overflow wants me to add more text, as "there's only code here!" but I literally don't know what to add. So, let me just tell you that I'm unsure EXACTLY what is wrong here. To me, all the logic checks out! It SHOULD work, and, for goodness sake, WHY DOES THE DOG MOVE, NOT THE BONE!

So you add a random value to the position, then you subtract a random value of the same range. Why do you believe it should do anything meaningful ?

Besides the weird random positioning of the "Doge", you should only seed the random-number generator once. Oh, and please don't write in all upper-case, that like shouting and it's rather rude to shout at the people you want to help you.

Vector2 BonePos = ... inside the if block creates a new, local variable representing its own object within that scope. It does not affect the earlier definition. The position used to render the bone is never altered. Turn your compiler warnings up to catch unused variables.

Vector2 BonePos = ... inside the if block creates a new, local variable representing its own object within that scope. It does not affect the earlier definition. The position used to render the bone is never altered.
Turn your compiler warnings up to catch unused variables.
Aside from that, reseeding the pRNG upon collision is questionable. Usually you call SetRandomSeed once near the start of the program, or simply allow InitWindow to implicitly seed the pRNG.
Also, it is unclear what the purpose of these jitters are
DogePos.x += GetRandomValue(1.0f,2.0f);
DogePos.x -= GetRandomValue(1.0f,2.0f);
DogePos.y -= GetRandomValue(1.0f,2.0f);
DogePos.y += GetRandomValue(1.0f,2.0f);

but they mean the position of the "doge" is randomly shifting each frame.

Overall, this appears to be a Snake-like game, with free movement. A refactored example follows.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "raylib.h"

#define WIDTH 300
#define HEIGHT 200
#define BOUND_RNG(X,Y) (GetRandomValue(10, (X) - (Y) - 10))

int main(void)
{
    InitWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Random");
    Rectangle doge = { .x = 50, .y = 50, .width = 20, .height = 20 };
    Rectangle bone = {
        .x = BOUND_RNG(WIDTH, 20),
        .y = BOUND_RNG(HEIGHT, 20),
        .width = 20,
        .height = 20
    };

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)) doge.x += 4.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT)) doge.x -= 4.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_UP)) doge.y -= 4.0f;
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_DOWN)) doge.y += 4.0f;

        if (CheckCollisionRecs(doge, bone)) {
            bone.x = BOUND_RNG(WIDTH, bone.width);
            bone.y = BOUND_RNG(HEIGHT, bone.height);
        }

        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(DARKGRAY);
        DrawRectangleRec(doge, YELLOW);
        DrawRectangleRec(bone, RED);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}


Note that this example does not handle the event where the "bone" randomly moves to an overlapped position with the "doge", or prevent the "doge" from moving outside the play area. It does prevent the "bone" from clipping outside the play area when respawning.

The random adding and subtraction is to make the dog shake

He's really happy

An actual game in C in around 25 lines of code is surprising to me.

@Harith If we had a library implementing a function "DoGame(game_name)", we could have one line :)

I'm using a graphics library, raylib, it does a LOT of the work and removes much of the tedium and difficulty.
